# Best way to implement a swipeable weekly calendar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Im implementing a rather simple weekly calendar view. The 7 days of the week with the day of the week name on top of each number. I want the user to be able to change weeks by swiping horizontally, something like calendar app does already.

My idea is to use UIScrollView with paging enabled to implement the scrolling, but I'm not exactly sure how many weeks ahead to load on the right or how many prior weeks on the left. ? Or when should I start removing calendar views left behind ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a mere scroll view, use a UIPageViewController in scroll mode. This solves the "infinite scrolling" problem that you are describing.